# Change Wordpress.org hosted plugin readme.txt

Tags: plugin-development, wordpress.org

is it possible to change the readme.txt of a plugin that is hosted at `http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/plugin-name` without tagging a new version?

I would like wordpress.org to show the new readme.txt.

I have added a link to the plugin documentation but I do not want to force the users of updating their version because of this change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just change the readme in the tagged directory that is marked as stable.

Comment: Hey, great. I thought that **every** update would also be a new available update for the users. I just gave it a try with a screenshot. Hope that works out. *Edit:* Yes, it works. Thanks a lot for the heads up!

Answer (score 1):

Afaik: No. We're all suffering from the wp.org plugin repo limitations...

Edit: This answer is *plain wrong*.

Comment: @AaronGibralter But missing the +1 vote ;)